# Ubuntu 16.04: Cron expression rejected, despite being ok according to several CRON sites

Tags: cron

I am trying to write this CRON expression in my CRONtab:

```
5/10 * * * *
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.9KFt2K/crontab":109: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

Why is this?

I have checked newlines and spaces and nothing seems to be wrong. This expression is seen as valid on http://crontab.guru/ and http://cron.schlitt.info/

Incidentally, line 109 is directly above the offensive line in the CRON, and not that line itself

**** EDIT for CRON example:

The original looked like this:

```
### Commented heading
*/10 * * * * /path-to-script.sh arg >> /pathtolog.log 2>&1
```

Then changed it to be this:

```
### Commented heading
2/10 * * * * /path-to-script.sh arg >> /pathtolog.log 2>&1
```

That gave an error. But the following worked:

```
### Commented heading
5-59/10 * * * * /path-to-script.sh arg >> /pathtolog.log 2>&1
```

Comment: If that's the entire line, you haven't specified a command. Even so, I just added that line to my own crontab (Vixie cron, Linux Mint), and it didn't complain. Perhaps the error is actually on line 109 (which you haven't shown us).

Comment: This worked: 5-59/10 * * * *. Do different versions  of Ubuntu have different CRON implementations?

Comment: As far as I know they all use Vixie cron (probably different versions). But you need to narrow down the problem and show us a complete cron file that shows the error message. You haven't even told us what's on line 109 (the line the error message refers to), nor have you told us what command is on the line starting with `5/10` (I presume you have *some* command there).